# Nodejs - Create Array of Objects from filesystem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, filesystems, fs

I am working on making a menu in my ReactApp that represents a folder structure. The folders are named by the category for the documents inside, some of the folders have sub-folders with files in there.

The basic output i'm looking for is something like this:

```
[
 {
  "Payroll Forms": {
      files: ["form1.pdf", "form2.pdf"],
      "Payroll How To's": {
          files: ["file1.pdf", "file2.doc"]
      },
      "Payroll Adjustments": {
          files: ["file1.doc", "file2.pdf"],
          "Payroll Subdirectory": {
              files: ["file1.xsl", "file2.pdf"]
          }
      }
  },
  {
   "LOA": {
      files: []
......(you get the idea)
]
```

Now this is a whole directory, so there would be an object for each top level directory which will have files and sub-directories within.

I am able to make this work with a finite number of sub-directories by hard coding how everything works. I do not want to limit them on what they are allowed to do, or have to go back in and add more code for another level of directories if they need it.

I have spent the better part of 2 days wracking my brain on how to automate this dynamically and have not gotten ANY closer which is why I have no starting code to work with.

Is there anyone out there who can lend a hand, I have no problem doing the work just need some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey tried something hope it helps:

```
const fs = require('fs');
//const folderObject = {files:[]}; //if the parent folder has files
const folderObject = {};
function parseFolder(obj, folderPath){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    for(file of files){
        const filePath = `${folderPath}/${file}`;
        if(fs.lstatSync(filePath).isDirectory()){
            obj[file] = {files:[]};
            parseFolder(obj[file],filePath);
        } else {
            obj.files.push(file);
        }
    }
}
parseFolder(folderObject,'./node_modules');
```

Change the './node_modules' to the folder path that you need to parse

Comment: That worked perfect!! Thank you so much, I my brain just couldn't wrap around how to do this for some reason lol.

Comment: No problem love the little mind workout. Let me know any other issues you run into, also mark this accepted so it would help others who are looking for such a solution.